# What does the \ra command do?

Tags: tables, macros

I'm trying to understand the following code. What does \ra do?

```
\begin{table*}\centering  
\ra{1.3}  
\begin{tabular}{@{}rrrrcrrrcrrr@{}}\toprule  
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \phantom{abc}& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} &
\phantom{abc} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule{2-4} \cmidrule{6-8} \cmidrule{10-12}
& $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$ && $t=0$ & $t=1$ & $t=2$\\ \midrule  
$dir=1$\\  
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 && 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 && -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\  
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384&& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143&& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\  
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721&& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930&& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\  
$dir=0$\\  
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119&& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764&& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\  
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591&& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000&& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\  
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351&& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326&& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\  
\bottomrule  
\end{tabular}  
\caption{Caption}  
\end{table*}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. I don't think that's a standard command, so presumably there is a definition of it somewhere in your file.

Comment: Most likely, you'll find something like `\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}`

Comment: That's it. I just saw the definition. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you'll find

```
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}
```

In your document, but I think you shouldn't use it. With `\ra{1.3}` the distance between rows will increase by 30%, which can be useful in certain situations, but here it will just spread out the data without any real benefit.

Rather, you should separate the two parts of the table with a small vertical space. Also the `\phantom{abc}` columns are just a waste of space. Using `siunitx` and `S` columns provides for consistent typesetting of numbers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}r*{9}{S[table-format=-3.4]}@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 8$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 16$} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{$w = 32$}\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7} \cmidrule(l){8-10}
& {$t=0$} & {$t=1$} & {$t=2$} & {$t=0$} & {$t=1$} & {$t=2$} & {$t=0$} & {$t=1$} & {$t=2$} \\
\midrule  
$dir=1$\\  
$c$ & 0.0790 & 0.1692 & 0.2945 & 0.3670 & 0.7187 & 3.1815 & -1.0032 & -1.7104 & -21.7969\\  
$c$ & -0.8651& 50.0476& 5.9384& -9.0714& 297.0923& 46.2143& 4.3590& 34.5809& 76.9167\\  
$c$ & 124.2756& -50.9612& -14.2721& 128.2265& -630.5455& -381.0930& -121.0518& -137.1210& -220.2500\\  
\addlinespace
$dir=0$\\  
$c$ & 0.0357& 1.2473& 0.2119& 0.3593& -0.2755& 2.1764& -1.2998& -3.8202& -1.2784\\  
$c$ & -17.9048& -37.1111& 8.8591& -30.7381& -9.5952& -3.0000& -11.1631& -5.7108& -15.6728\\  
$c$ & 105.5518& 232.1160& -94.7351& 100.2497& 141.2778& -259.7326& 52.5745& 10.1098& -140.2130\\  
\bottomrule  
\end{tabular}  
\caption{Caption}  
\end{table*}  

\end{document}
```

[image]